# R - Distinct count across columns

Tags: r, distinct-values

I have a large and complex dataset (a bit too complex to share here, and probably not necessary to share the whole thing) but here's an example of what it looks like. This is just one day and the full sample spans hundreds of days:

[image: Sample Data]

What I want to do, is to devise a way to count variation of the `Genre` within each `Row`. To put it more simply (I hope): each `Row` has 12 `Column`s and I want to measure the variation of `Genre` across those 12 `Column`s (it's the BBC iPlayer, which many of you might be familiar with). E.g. If a `Row` is comprised of 4 "sport", 4 "drama", and 4 "documentary", there would be a distinct count of 3 genres.

I'm thinking that a simple distinct count would be a good way to measure variation within each row (the more distinct the count, the higher the variation) but it's not a very nuanced approach. I.e. if a row is comprised of 11 "sport" and 1 "documentary" it's a distinct count of 2. If it's comprised of 6 "sport" and 6 "documentary" it's still a distinct count of 2 - so distinct count doesn't really help in that sense.

I guess I'm asking for advice on two things here:

- Firstly, what would be the most appropriate way to measure variation
  of `Genre` within each `Row`
- Secondly, how would I go about doing that! I.e. what code / packages would I need?

I hope that's all clear, but if not, I'd be happy to elaborate on anything. It's perhaps worth noting (as I mentioned above) that I want to determine variation on a specific date, and the sample data shared here is just one date (but I have hundreds).

Thanks in advance :)

*** Update ***

Thanks for the comments below - especially about sharing a snapshot of the real data (which you'll find below). My apologies - I'm a bit of a novice in this area and not really familiar with the proper conventions!

Here's a sample of the data - I hope it's right and I hope it helps:

```
structure(list(Row = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Genre = c("", "Sport", "Drama", "Documentary", 
"Entertainment", "Drama", "Comedy", "Crime Drama", "Entertainment", 
"Documentary", "Entertainment", "History", "Crime Drama", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Drama", "Drama", 
"Documentary", "Entertainment", "Period Drama"), Column = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I understand your full dataset is large and too cumbersome to add here, but given your description, you can easily provide *something*. It doesn't have to be real. Since you only care about `Row`, `Column`, and `Genre`, why not just generate a frame such as `set.seed(42); sampdata <- transform(expand.grid(Row=0:3, Column=1:12), Genre=sample(c("A","B","C"), size=48, replace=TRUE))`? (Frankly, we don't need the code to generate it, you could also randomly create it then post the output from `dput(sampdata)` to your question; it's the gold-standard for unambiguous data.)

Comment: BTW, I edited your question to clarify the difference between "row" and `Row` (a column name), since frames often refer to columns and rows in a literal sense, as well as case-differences in column names (`genre`-vs-`Genre`). I hope I didn't mis-interpret, I think my edit provides clarity.

Comment: Or indeed share a snapshot of your real data with `dput(YOURDATA[1:30, c("Row", "Genre", "Column")])`

Comment: As for your first question, there's probably a large number of more or less appropriate ways to summarize the variability, you could calculate the standard deviation, the number of unique counts, some Gini-like coefficient etc.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans and deschen for your feedback. Have updated the original post to include some real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducible sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
sampdata <- transform(
  expand.grid(Date = Sys.Date() + 0:2, Row=0:3, Column=1:12), 
  Genre = sample(c("Crime Drama","Documentary","Drama","Entertainment"), 
                 size = 48, replace = TRUE)
)
head(sampdata)
#         Date Row Column         Genre
# 1 2022-02-18   0      1   Crime Drama
# 2 2022-02-19   0      1   Crime Drama
# 3 2022-02-20   0      1   Crime Drama
# 4 2022-02-18   1      1   Crime Drama
# 5 2022-02-19   1      1   Documentary
# 6 2022-02-20   1      1 Entertainment
nrow(sampdata)
# [1] 144
```

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can group, summarize, then pivot:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
sampdata %>%
  group_by(Date, Row) %>%
  summarize(
    Uniq = n_distinct(Genre),
    Var = var(table(Genre))
  ) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    Date, names_from = Row, values_from = c(Uniq, Var)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 9
#   Date       Uniq_0 Uniq_1 Uniq_2 Uniq_3 Var_0 Var_1 Var_2 Var_3
#   <date>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2022-02-18      2      3      2      2     0     3    18    18
# 2 2022-02-19      3      3      1      3     3     3    NA     3
# 3 2022-02-20      2      3      3      3    18     3     3     3
```

Two things: `Uniq_#` is per-`Row` counts of distinct `Genre` values, and `Var_#` are the *variance* of the counts. For instance, in your example, two genres with counts 6 and 6 will have a variance of `0`, but counts of 11 and 1 will have a variance of 50 (`var(c(11,1))`), indicating more variation for that `Date`/`Row` combination.

Because we use `group_by`, if you have even more grouping variables, it is straight-forward to extend this, both in the grouping and in what aggregation we can do in addition to `n_distinct(.)` and `var(.)`.

BTW: depending on your other calculations, analysis, and reporting/plotting, it might be useful to keep this in the *long* format, removing the `pivot_wider`.

```r
sampdata %>%
  group_by(Date, Row) %>%
  summarize(
    Uniq = n_distinct(Genre),
    Var = var(table(Genre))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#    Date         Row  Uniq   Var
#    <date>     <int> <int> <dbl>
#  1 2022-02-18     0     2     0
#  2 2022-02-18     1     3     3
#  3 2022-02-18     2     2    18
#  4 2022-02-18     3     2    18
#  5 2022-02-19     0     3     3
#  6 2022-02-19     1     3     3
#  7 2022-02-19     2     1    NA
#  8 2022-02-19     3     3     3
#  9 2022-02-20     0     2    18
# 10 2022-02-20     1     3     3
# 11 2022-02-20     2     3     3
# 12 2022-02-20     3     3     3
```

Good examples of when to keep it long include further aggregation by `Date`/`Row` and plotting with `ggplot2` (which really rewards long-data).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans - the second table you produced is exactly what I'm looking for. However, when I try to run this code (without the `pivot_wider` part) it only produces a single value for `Uniq` and `Var` (i.e. not a value for every date in the df). Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong? When I try it with the `pivot_wider` line I get the following error: "Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Row` doesn't exist." Have checked the data and `Row` is definitely written that way (with an upper case "R").

Comment: All  I can say is that it works with my data. Your sample data doesn't have the `Date` field that you say is necessary, so I made my own. Can you update your sample data in your question?

Comment: What is your version of `dplyr` and `tidyr`?

Comment: dplyr = 1.0.7.  Tidyr = 1.1.3. Just checked and I see that there are more recent versions of both. I'll update them and see if that works!

Comment: Those versions should be able to support what code I've given, so the upgrade isn't critical in my mind. At this point, I don't think I can help much more without updated data and possibly (if different) the updated code you used and its error(s).

Comment: Ok - finally got a chance to test this again today. I rebooted R (hadn't closed it down in a while) and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

First create some reproducible data. All we need is `Row` and `Genre`:

```
set.seed(42)
Row <- rep(1:10, each=10)
Genre <- sample(c("Sport", "Drama", "Documentary", "Entertainment", "History", "Crime Drama", "Period Drama", "Film - Comedy", "Film-Thriller"), 100, replace=TRUE)
example <- data.frame(Row, Genre)
str(example)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Row  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Genre: chr  "Sport" "History" "Sport" "Film-Thriller" ...
```

Now to get the number of different genres in each row:

```
Count <- tapply(example$Genre, example$Row, function(x) length(unique(x)))
Count
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#  7  5  6  7  6  8  7  7  7  6
```

There are 7 genres in row 1 and only 5 in row 2. For more detail:

```
xtabs(~Genre+Row, example)
#                 Row
#  Genre           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#    Crime Drama   0 0 1 1 3 1 1 0 2  1
#    Documentary   0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1  0
#    Drama         1 1 1 3 2 1 2 1 1  0
#    Entertainment 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 2 0  0
#    Film - Comedy 1 0 3 2 0 1 2 2 0  2
#    Film-Thriller 1 3 0 0 0 1 1 1 2  2
#    History       1 3 0 1 2 1 2 2 2  1
#    Period Drama  1 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 1  2
#    Sport         3 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 1  2
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like it'll do the job! I might not get a chance to test this out until next week but will mark the answer as correct as soon as I know it works for me :) By the way, the full df has hundreds of dates - I assume I'd need to modify this code to take date into account? Ideally the final output/df would include the following columns: date, row, distinct_count

Comment: Yes, you could incorporate date into the process by splitting your data frame into a list of data frames, one for each date and then running the code for each date using `lapply()`.